# The number after "more" in the footer is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, footer

The footer of this page lists 9 sites in the Science category, and then adds "more (3)". Clicking that "more (3)" link brings up a [page with 19 science sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-questions). Considering that 19-9=10, I think that the number 3 should be 10.

Comment: I think that they are all incorrect. Life and Arts is also wrong - says there are 19 when there is 27. The error here I assume is that when new sites are created they aren't counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bunch of sites in private beta were not setup correctly so were not counted in the footer for their category.